# How to achieve windowSplashScreenBrandingImage in Android below 12 after migrating to new SplashScreen api

Tags: android, android-styles, android-12, android-api-levels, android-splashscreen

I've followed [Migrate your splash screen implementation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate#migrate_your_splash_screen_implementation), and it promises that ***After you migrate using the SplashScreen compat library, the system displays the same splash screen on all versions of Android.***

I've created the new splash theme, but the issue is that, I don't have an option to put **windowSplashScreenBrandingImage** for style belowe values-v31, that is, for android lower than 12.
So the bottom bar that we have been using previously can'be shown as of now.

values-v31/style

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.SplashThemeNew" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_icon</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">
            @drawable/background_splash_12_bottom_strp
        </item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

style

```
 <style name="Theme.App.SplashThemeNew" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_icon</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

**While according to the Migration guide, it should be possible, Has anyone some ideas about this?**

**Thanks for your time and attention.**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use the `android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage` on api lower than 31. This issue has officially been reported as a feature request on the IssueTracker, but for now they say that it won't be implemented ([Source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194301890#comment7)). However, it is still assigned so it might get implemented in the future.

Besides that, the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) state that The design guidelines recommend against using a branding image.

That being said, I found an [Medium](https://medium.com/@radomir9720/android-splash-screen-easy-setup-for-both-11-version-and-lower-and-12-287ccb86f9c7) article that might help you achieve what you are looking for.